# Sort by multiple values with sortBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I would like to sort an `RDD[(Int,Int)]` by it's first and second value in order to have something like that.

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1)....]
```

I tried that

```
rdd.sortBy( x => (x._1,x._2) )
```

But it's seem to not work even if it compile, it sort just by the first value.

Maybe i could put each result of the first sorting in a different partition and next apply a sort on the second value.

Comment: What makes you think it does only sort by the first value? It seems to work for me, as you can check with `val ord = implicitly[Ordering[(Int,Int)]].lt _; println(ord((0,1), (0,0)), ord((0,0), (0,1)))`.

Comment: It seems to sort fine. I've just tried `sc.parallelize(0 to 20).map(x => x % 4 -> -x % 3).sortBy(identity).take(20)` in `spark-shell`. Can you include an example in your question that can be run in the `spark-shell` and demonstrates the curious behavior?

Comment: I'm a dum, i use rdd.foreach(println) which gives me an unordered respresentation, i've used collect and it shows good results...
Sorry and thank you for your time.

Comment: `rrd.sorted` in this case (ordering by `_1` and then by `_2`).

Comment: Ah, yes, `foreach` will run in parallel on the partitions, so the order of the output is unpredictable. Nice figuring it out! I'd recommend adding this as an answer, because others may make the same mistake.

Comment: Just a note: `x => (x._1,x._2)` is the identity function for a tuple! You're unpacking the elements, only to re-assemble them

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that

```
rdd.sortBy(x=>(x._1,x._2))
```

works.

I totally forget that i was displaying the result with foreach wich display an rdd in an unordered way.
After the use of collect/take(n) results were what i was looking for.

So to make sure that your sorting works do NOT use

```
rdd.foreach(println)
```

But use

```
rdd.collect.foreach(println)
```